# How to allow audio to be triggered by the user in a webapp on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications

I've built a webapp which plays some audio ('audioElement') when the user triggers an event ('languageSelect').

The clearConversationHistory function triggers some other functions:

After the conversation is cleared, an API request is sent to ChatGPT. The response from that is then converted to speech using Google Text-to-Speech API. The audio is then returned, and that is the audioElement below:

```
languageSelect.addEventListener("change", function() {

  clearConversationHistory();
  
  audioElement.play();

});
```

It works in any browser on Android and Windows, but isn't working in either Chrome or Safari on iOS devices (have tested on iPhone 11 and iPad).

I've read that to play audio you need direct, physical and synchronous interaction from the user. I'm guessing that the problem is that, because of the intermediate steps (the API calls), the audio isn't been playing synchronously. Is there any way for the audio to play after the APIs have been called?

I found this in [Apple's Safari HTML5 audio and video documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW1). It says that you can play audio/video in sequence, so I tried adding a silent mp3 file which plays while the API calls are executed, and then the audioElement plays sequentially afterwards:

```
const unlockAudioElement = new Audio("static/silence.mp3");

    languageSelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
      console.log("Language select event triggered.");

      // Play the silence.mp3 file
      unlockAudioElement.play();
      console.log("Playing silence.mp3...");

      // After the silence.mp3 file has finished playing,
        // execute clearConversationHistory() and play the audioElement
        clearConversationHistory();
        console.log("Conversation history cleared.");

      // Add an event listener to the 'ended' event of the unlockAudioElement
      unlockAudioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        console.log("silence.mp3 finished playing.");

        audioElement.play();
        console.log("Playing audioElement...");
      });
    });
```

EDIT: Resolved. I ended up having to create a new button. Now, the languageSelect event plays the silent audio, which unlocks the audio. After that, when the user clicks the new button, it plays the audioElement. Not ideal for user experience, but will have to do.